# Redirect don't work with afterModel

Tags: ember.js

I have the following route:

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(model) {
//    model.ensureAllData();
  },
  redirect: function  (model) {
    this.transitionTo('user.followers', model);
  }
});
```

After adding the `afterModel` hook, the redirection don't work anymore, even the code in the hook commented out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should put the `transitionTo` into the `afterModel` hook and remove the `redirect` at all, if I'm not mistaken it was [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L278) in favor to the `afterModel`:

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(model) {
    //model.ensureAllData();
    this.transitionTo('user.followers', model);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is a difference between `afterModel` and `redirect` : A  `transitionTo` in the `afterModel` invalidates previously loaded models when a `transitionTo` in the `redirect` doesn't. Plus I couldn't find any deprecation notice for the `redirect` hook. Can you update the link ?

Comment: @mbritto Helpful explanation. I had a transitionTo called in an afterModel hook that rendered a show page if the model had a firstObject. I ran into trouble when I had a route that loaded a global and local result for the same model. The global was loaded first and so was always being overridden by the transitionTo in the afterModel hook. Changing the transition to be called from the redirect honored the first model.